# Range-based for loop equivalent

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

So according to [n2243](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2243.html#the-range-based-for-statement) the range-based for loop is equivalent to this:

```
{
     auto && __range = ( expression );

     for ( auto __begin = std::Range<_RangeT>::begin(__range),
                  __end = std::Range<_RangeT>::end(__range);
          __begin != __end;
          ++__begin )
     {
         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
         statement
     }    
}
```

It then says `2 If the header <iterator_concept> is not included prior to a use of the range-based for statement, the program is ill-formed.` so I question how up to date this is. I'm also curious what `std::Range` is or if it's purely an implementation detail. The closest I can find is [n3350](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3350.html).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10821839/1508519) relies on this information and says:

> Range for is as fast as possible since it caches the end
>   iterator[citation], uses pre-increment and only dereferences the
>   iterator once.
>
> so if you tend to write:
>
> `for(iterator i = cont.begin(); i != cont.end(); i++) { /**/ }`
>
> Then, yes, range-for may be slightly faster, since it's also easier to
>   write there's no reason not to use it (when appropriate).
>
> P.S. I said it's as fast as possible, it isn't however faster than
>   possible. You can achieve the exact same performance if you write your
>   manual loops carefully.

I'm curious if it actually makes a difference now. As far as I can see it's just syntactic sugar. For example, in a loop where you could do `auto it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it`, it would require boiler plate code that returns reverse iterators where the ranged-based for loop expects `begin` and `end`. And if all it saves is typing, then what other advantages does it offer, since it **only** expects `begin` and `end`? I'm curious if the answer I quoted above still holds weight since the paper is from 2007.

Comment: This proposal (N2243) is quite old (is it the second on this topic?), it has been revised multiple times. The latest *individual* paper I can find about it is [N2930](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html) and there's still a defect discussed in [N3257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3257.pdf). Consider using [N3337](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or the Standard itself as a source of how it's now defined. The `std::Range` part has been replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DyP says, this section has changed a bit in the final standard. C++11 6.5.4 The range-based `for` statement [stmt.ranged]:

> 1 For a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> ```
>   for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
> ```
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the *expression* surrounded by parentheses
>
> ```
>   ( expression )
> ```
>
> and for a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> ```
>   for ( for-range-declaration : braced-init-list ) statement
> ```
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the *braced-init-list*. In each case, a range-based `for` statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
>   {
>     auto && __range = range-init;
>     for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>                __end = end-expr;
>           __begin != __end;
>           ++__begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>       statement
>     }
>   }
> ```
>
> where `__range`, `__begin`, and `__end` are variables defined for exposition only, and `_RangeT` is the type of the expression, and *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are determined as follows:
>
> - if `_RangeT` is an array type, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `__range` and `__range + __bound`, respectively, where `__bound` is the array bound. If `_RangeT` is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
> - if `_RangeT` is a class type, the *unqualified-ids* `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, *begin-expr*
>     and *end-expr* are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`, respectively;
> - otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2). For the purposes of this name lookup,
>     namespace `std` is an associated namespace.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
>   int array[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
>   for (int& x : array)
>     x *= 2;
> ```
>
> —end example ]
>
> 2 In the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *for-range-declaration*, each *decl-specifier* shall be either a *type-specifier* or `constexpr`.

Comment: This also raises the question if there's already some source for Standard drafts formatted as SO-compatible Markdown/HTML (maybe derived from the latex source?) ;)

Comment: @DyP That would be incredible, we should start a project to implement a translator.

Comment: I think I withdraw the comment about the blockquote. It doesn't exactly improve readability.. As for the markdown: A quick google search showed up [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html), will give that a try (it's also under GPL).

Comment: @DyP I think it's a bit better without the white vs. gray separation.