What would happen if I append elements in range based for?
I want to modify (push_back) element while iterate vector like this:
auto main() -> int {
    std::vector<double> v { 1, 2, 3 };

    for (auto& num : v) {
        std::cout << num << "\n";
        v.push_back(num);
    }

    std::cout << "===========\n";

    for (const auto& num : v) {
        std::cout << num << "\n";
    }
}

The output is:
1
1.00938e-320
0
===========
1
2
3
1
1.00938e-320
0

Why the output is not something like this:
1
2
3
===========
1
2
3
1
2
3

If range based for is just sugar of:
for (auto& it{v.begin()}, it != v.end(), it++)

Shouldn't there be two possible situations here?

v.end() evalued every iterate and never end. It should be an infinite loop.

v.end() evalued one time before iterate and should output as I expected:


1
2
3
===========
1
2
3
1
2
3


Ranged-based for loops are syntax sugar for iterators, and std::vector iterators get invalidated on push_back. So what you have is undefined behaviour.

You forgot about the possibility of the vector reallocating. When it does, all iterators are invalidated. Writing a valid loop over a vector that adds elements to it is tricky.

not related to your problem, but worth mentioning: "If range based for is just sugar of:
for (auto& it{v.begin()}, it != v.end(), it++)" Well, not quite. Here is the correct equivalent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20761976/2805305 There are a few important differences, like end being evaluated just once.

You should really consider what you're trying to accomplish, and why you would ever want to do something like this.

https://godbolt.org/z/j9476qTd1

As you can see when you call std::vector::push_back:

If after the operation the new size() is greater than old capacity() a
reallocation takes place, in which case all iterators (including the
end() iterator) and all references to the elements are invalidated.
Otherwise only the end() iterator is invalidated.

(emphasis is mine)
Range-based loop is only a syntactic sugar for using the iterators.
During push_back the vector might need to be resized and reallocated. In this case all iterators are invalidated including the one used as the "current" in the loop.
Using it will lead to undefined-behavior.
Even without reallocation you get into problems checking the end():
It is queried once before the loop starts.
There is a subtle difference from C++17. But in any case calling push_back inside the loop will invokes undefined-behavior because the end() queried before the loop is no longer valid.
This means the standard gives no guarantee for the output of the program. Any output you observe is legitimate.

"compare to the end() iterator after each iteration" is misleading. The end() iterator is determined only once before the first iteration.

@j6t you are right, corrected.

All ranged-based for loops call end once. The change in C++17 was that end can now return a sentinel with a different type.

@PasserBy reading cppreference again I see that you are right - updated the answer accordingly.
