# Iterator two dimensional list

Tags: c++, arrays, list, iterator, std-pair

I am trying to scroll a two dimensional list with an iterator and I know that I'm missing something but I don't know what.

So the idea is that I'll have some commands to parse.

[image: schema of my list]

I put them on a list then I want to check if a member of the list is equal to "data.txt" for example. So I did an iterator for this, but as it is a two dimensional list with an std::pair inside it, I don't know how to implement this iterator. I did this but it isn't good, I can't read both list.

```
typedef std::list<std::string>  listStr;

std::list <std::pair<listStr, int> >  _execCmd;


int     Parser::execCmd()
{
   std::list<std::string>::const_iterator i;

   for (i = _execCmd.front().first.begin(); i != _execCmd.back().first.end(); ++i)                                          
    {                                                         
      if (*i == "Search.txt")                                       
        execSearch();                                          
      else if (*i == "data.txt")                                  
        execData();
    }
  return (0);
}
```

In that case, I stay on the first list "File.txt data.txt contact.txt" (cf: schema) and I can go through the second list "Search.txt employe.csv".

I've tried this too:

```
int     Parser::execCmd()
{
  std::list<std::pair<listStr, int> >::const_iterator i;

  for (i = _execCmd.begin(); i != _execCmd.end(); ++i)        
   {
     if (*i == "Search.txt")                                    
        execSearch();                                  
     else if (*i == "data.txt")                               
        execData();                           
   }
  return (0);
}
```

But I can't compile this because I don't know how to compare the iterator with a string (`*i == "help"`)

Somebody can help me please ?

Comment: A side note: why don't you use the foreach syntax, i.e. `for(auto& i: _execCmd) {}`. It's much cleaner and gives you directly the element.

Comment: This project is for school and the "auto" is not allowed. :/

Comment: Just use `std::pair<listStr, int>&` instead of auto! You can also make a `typedef` for it to make it even more cleaner. And in your case, it will guide you directly to the answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::pair<X,Y>` contains two members, `first` which obtains the member of type `X` and `second` which obtains the member of type `Y`.

In your case, thanks to the `typedef` you have a `std::list<std::pair<std::list<std::string>, int> >`.

So to iterate over all `std::string`s in that structure,  you need to iterate over the outer list to get the pairs, obtain the `first` member from each of those (of type `std::list<string>`, and iterate over ever element of that inner list.

```
int Parser::execCmd()
{
    std::list<std::pair<listStr, int> >::const_iterator i;

    for (i = _execCmd.begin(); i != _execCmd.end(); ++i)        
    {
        // i->first is of type std::list<std:string>

        for (j = i->first.begin(); j != i->first.end(); ++j)
        {
             if (*j == "Search.txt")                                    
                 execSearch();                                  
             else if (*j == "data.txt")                               
                 execData();                           
        }
   }
   return (0);
}
```

In C++11, it is simpler, but still necessary to nest loops.

```
int Parser::execCmd()
{
    std::list<std::pair<listStr, int> >::const_iterator i;

    for (const auto &i : _execCmd))        
    {
        // i.first is of type std::list<std:string>

        for (const auto &j : i.first)
        {
             if (j == "Search.txt")                                    
                 execSearch();                                  
             else if (j == "data.txt")                               
                 execData();                           
        }
   }
   return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, *the way* to iterate over an `std::list` in c++ is to use the foreach syntax.

The idea of an *iterator* is to give you a pointer-like access to elements in the container *and* to provide a way for the container to operate on these elements. For example, given an iterator you can delete an element in a list. Or you could insert an element at specific position.

What *you* need, however, is just to traverse over the list elements and check whether there is "search.txt" or "data.txt". So you don't need any iterators, you need just the elements. This is what the range-based for loop in c++ is. (Look at this great question: [What is the correct way of using C++11's range-based for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15927033/3132718))

*Note* that internally the range-based for loop internally [*may use* iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10822280/3132718).

```
  std::list<std::pair<listStr, int> >::const_iterator i;

  for (std::pair<listStr, int> &elementFromOuterList: _execCmd) {
      // now given that elementFromOuterList you can do whatever you need to
  }
```